# Represent a Number as a Binary in C#

Tags: c#

I have four checkboxes and user can select any check box and I want to store checked checkboxes in a single value. Logic should be like

`Item                     Value
Checkbox1                 1
Checkbox2                 2
Checkbox3                 4
Checkbox4                 8`

If a user selects Checkbox1 and Checkbox2 then it should be stored 3 If select Checkbox1, Checkbox2 and Checkbox3 then it should be stored 7. It will store some of value. Now I want to derive selected checkboxes from stored value, that means if a value is 7 then Checkbox1, Checkbox2 and Checkbox3 are selected.

How can I achieve this? If any can help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine which checkboxes should be checked, use the [bitwise AND operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx):

```
Checkbox1.Checked = value & 1;
Checkbox2.Checked = value & 2;
Checkbox3.Checked = value & 4;
Checkbox4.Checked = value & 8;
```

Comment: it shoud be OR operator

Comment: It should be `OR` when storing the value, but I assume that the OP already succeeded in doing this. (Probably using `+` instead of `|`.)

Answer (score 0):

use an `enum` with the [Flags](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-flags) attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum CheckBoxEnum
{
   Value1 = 1,
   Value2 = 2,
   Value3 = 4,
   Value4 = 8,
}
```

You can then check the results using bitwise operations:

```
var res = CheckBoxEnum.Value1 | CheckBoxEnum.Value2;
var res2 = CheckBoxEnum.Value1 & CheckBoxEnum.Value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** 
@Glorfindel answer is more elegant, but you should use Bitwise OR instead of AND

```
Checkbox1.Checked = value | 1;
Checkbox2.Checked = value | 2;
Checkbox3.Checked = value | 4;
Checkbox4.Checked = value | 8;
```

You are looking for [FlagsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), applied to `Enum`

```
[Flags]
public enum CheckboxesSelected
{
    Checkbox1 = 1,
    Checkbox2 = 2,
    Checkbox3 = 4,
    Checkbox4 = 8
}
```

Then:
if your checkboxes controls is selected, you can do something like this:

```
CheckboxesSelected result = CheckboxesSelected.Checkbox1 | CheckboxesSelected.Checkbox2; //result will be 3
```